# Operating Hamiltonian on discrete variable state

Tags: quantum-state, qutip, programming, hamiltonian

I have a hamiltonian consisting of combinations of a and a(dragger). i need to act this on discrete variable state like |0,0,0,1> and so on. Is there any library to do these kinds of operations?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Do you want to simulate the hamiltonian classically?

Answer (score 0):

[QuTip](https://qutip.org/) is a popular library for simulating dynamics of quantum systems.